# Can't update a product data with Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm having a problem in updating a product data.

The strange thing is that this problem is evidently connected to websites to which this product is assigned to. For some reason if the product is assigned to website A, I can't update the product's data - *the "save" action is not executed*.

But for website B, I can modify all the product's data. But if I try to assign a product to website A, I have the same problem and saving is not done. I compared the data for many websites and I can't spot anything that could be the cause for this.

I'm using Magento CE 1.4.2.0. Upgrade to the latest version is in progress, but I would still like to know what caused this.

Comment: Maybe some extension you're using?

Comment: I didn't add any new extensions, but some new webshops were created. It's really weird that for some webshops the save function is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also noticed that I can't apply the catalog rules anymore - I got the error

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Luckily we had a backup copy of the system and there everything worked ok. As I compared the code I couldn't spot any difference that could be the cause of this problem, so I took a look in data base. As soon as I copied the data tables used for catalog rules (`catalogrule`, `catalogrule_product`, `catalogrule_group_website`, `catalogrule_product_price`) from the working backup copy and place it into the broken one, everything started working ok - the product saving and applying of the catalog rules. I still don't know how this happened and will have to do a data table comparison and maybe get my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `catalogrule_product_price`s primary key is `int(10)`. So when all keys were used up, the last valid key is 4294967295, see [Numeric Datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html). Try to change it to `BIGINT` and everything should work again.